How does operator precedence affect the evaluation of $x = false && print 'printed' || true;?
I'm trying to understand why this expression:
$x = false && print 'printed' || true;
results in $x being false instead of true. I know that && has higher precedence than ||, but I'm confused about how the combination of &&, ||, and print works here. Can someone explain the exact evaluation process, step by step, in terms of operator precedence and short-circuit evaluation?

So $x will be true when both operands of && will be true. Left operand of && is false.

@u_mulder I think OP assumes the order of operations is (false && print 'printed') || true, hence they expect true. (Given the "I know that && has higher precedence than ||".)

The machine sees it as $x = false && (print 'printed' || true);

I think this is about php print.

This behavior is mentioned in the manual: print is not a function but a language construct. Its argument is the expression following the print keyword, and is not delimited by parentheses.

With an example from the PHP manual for print and the comments from @Jakkapong Rattananen, @shingo and @
Sergey Ligus I came to the following conclusion:
As print is a language construct, evaluation is a bit different there. The example is the following:
print "hello " && print "world";
// outputs "world1"; print "world" is evaluated first,
// then the expression "hello " && 1 is passed to the left-hand print

This is similar to your expression, but differs in the way that two prints are used.
So when the print after the && is evaluated first (and always returns 1), then probably the next operator || is evaluated next (left to right), so the whole expression is evaluated as if it were written
$x = false && (print 'printed' || true);

If you wrote it just a little bit different, it evaluates as you expected it, just according to operator precedence:
$x = false && 1 || true; 

Here $x is false. So the difference is really the "language construct" nature of print.

Both && and || work only with boolean operands, .i.e., true and false. All other types must be converted to a boolean first.
print is a language construct which returns an int. So in order to evaluate the expression, you must first evaluate print 'printed' || true and convert 1 to true. Then your actual expression is just false && true.
If you are confused about why the || is part of the print operand, it's because there are no parentheses to tell print that only the string should be the operand. print can also display values of other types such as boolean.

$x = false && print 'printed' || true;
This run in two sets

false && print 'printed'  (short circuit expressions in PHP?)
answer from 1. || true

$x is true in this case

Order of && and ||, or  || and `&&

&& (Logical AND): Higher precedence.
|| (Logical OR): Lower precedence.


https://ideone.com/Exq8FS

interestingly the result of the given expression is not true but false. And the OP asks "why?"

Logically speaking you are correct. In terms of language you are incorrect. There is a thing called Operator Precedence. Which is saying that both && and || have left Associativity and it will look like you are saying. But because print is a function that does return value it will be evaluated first and then if you look at link before again you end up in a situation were we have Undefined order of evaluation and the final expression will  be as nice_dev showed in a comment $x = false && (print 'printed' || true);
